# JSF scheduleEntryMoveEvent.getScheduleEvent() produce a different Object

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, hashmap

I have been working with implementing drag feature into `<p:schedule` prime face Calendar

In order to identify, on which event that i have clicked, i at first added the ScheduleEvent into the HashMap.

ie This happens when i load the calendar.

```
// this happens first 
   private HashMap<ScheduleEvent,Service> eventObjectMap=new HashMap<ScheduleEvent,Service>();
// the event is now created
    scheduleEvent=new DefaultScheduleEvent(details, date, endDate, "text"); 
// the event is now added to the calendar using 
    addEvent(scheduleEvent);
// Event is then added to the hashMap
    eventObjectMap.put(scheduleEvent, myObject);
```

Now i have a hashMap with key as ScheduleEvent and value as the corresponding Object.

It works fine `onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent)`, i get `myObject` using this

```
myObject=eventServiceMap.get((ScheduleEvent)selectEvent.getObject())
```

**But on `onEventMove(ScheduleEntryMoveEvent scheduleEntryMoveEvent)` I
  am not getting the any matching object from the hashMap.**

> Something has Happened in between and i am getting a different
>   ScheduleEvent object. So the key is considered as different. I have
>   verified that the ScheduleEvent values, they are the same as the original
>   event.

```
eventObjectMap.containsKey(event.getScheduleEvent())
```

**is always false**

Comment: Does DefaultScheduleEvent (or the ScheduleEvent in general) implement hashCode()?

Comment: @EdH yes the hashCode is also different !

Comment: My guess is hashCode() is not implemented, which means each Object will have a different hashCode() value.  I would suggest not using the object as the hashKey, but something you can use which implements the hashCode() method.  Right now, it looks like the evetn object is not suitable for use as a key to a hashmap

Comment: Can u explain how to implement hashcode function..??

Comment: Joshua Bloch explains it far better than I. http://www.scribd.com/doc/36454091/Effective-Java-Chapter3

Comment: @Dileep which PrimeFaces version?

Comment: @EdH i looked into it but wont help. I have now override the DefaultScheduleEvent and created another constructor which will accept object. Its a good work around but i really like to know how this issue can be solved

Comment: @MicheleMariotti primeface v 4.0

Comment: @EdH `DefaultScheduledEvent` overrides `hashCode()` and `equals()` and its implementation is ok

Comment: @Dileep make sure `title`, `startDate` and `endDate` are not null, since `equals()` only checks these

Comment: @MicheleMariotti Yes i did checked it.

Comment: @Dileep is your bean at least `@ViewScoped`? is your `eventObjectMap` full, when calling `containsKey()` inside `onEventMove()`?

Comment: @MicheleMariotti No my eventObjectMap contains the values, there is no scope issues. I have used getKeYset to get the key and also getValues for getting the values.  Sorry for the late reply

Comment: @Dileep i'm sorry, i'm out of ideas... that's very strange, indeed.

Comment: @MicheleMariotti Me too.. Lets wait for someone to get the answer :)

Comment: @Dileep however i met a similar issue using lazy loading, but i was (wrongly) comparing events id which were different on each `LazyScheduleModel.loadEvents()` call, because of auto-generated UUID inside `LazyScheduleModel.addEvent()`. good luck :)